# How to re-render a View without inserting data into fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

let's look at the code below. When the compiler goes out from the `HttpPost` action I want to redisplay the **blank** View with the `msg` object. How to do that? I don't want to use jQuery to clear fields because I have many DropDownLists being stored in the ViewData dictionary (in the `HttpGet` action).

I've read the topic [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter) (the Kurt's answer) but I don't want to modify my URL.

The code below redisplay all inserted data into the View.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {       
        /*insert many objects to the ViewData dictionary*/     

        return View("Add");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Item myObj)
    {
        /*do some action*/

        ViewData["msg"] = "blabla";

        return View("Add");
    }
```

Comment: So you **don't** want to change anything in the view after post, is that it?

Comment: I want to have all fields cleared

Answer (score 3):

Try clearing the modelstate:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Item myObj)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewData["msg"] = "blabla";
    return View("Add");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend implementing the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) in conjunction with `TempData` to display a message.