# passing multiple parameters in url in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have action method in controller called "Registration" as

```
public ActionResult Facility(int id = 0, int contractId = 0)
```

when I call this method from url like

```
/Registration/Facility/0?contractId=0
```

it works fine. Now when I try to construct above url in another method like

```
return RedirectToAction("Facility/0?contractId="+ model.ContractId);
```

it doesn't work, the url in browser is not constructed well it comes like

```
/Registration/Facility/0%3fcontractId%3d0
```

can anyone please tell me what wrong I'm doing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Facility", new { id = 0, contractId = model.ContractId});
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter/1257632#1257632)

Comment: thanks jao, it worked. But can you tell me why my code is not working, is there any rule that we have to use New{....} for constructing url?

Comment: Your code is not working because that overload of the method automatically escapes the ? and / characters so that you don't have to (it assumes that if you wanted to pass parameters, you'd use the overload which accepts parameters). Remember, the parameter is not an URL, it is an action name. Use Redirect if you want to supply a URL

Comment: that's well explained.....it's my ignorance, i could have checked the method signature before. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in method overload for redirecting. Pass in an anonymous object with the values you want

```
return RedirectToAction("Facility", new { id = 0, contractId = model.ContractId });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the parameters like below:

```
return RedirectToAction("Facility", new { contractId = model.ContractId });
```