# .NET MVC - How to get JsonResult from another Controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to get JSON result from another Controller and pass it back to client,
here is the scenario:

> using JQuery **Client** request for JSON from **Controller A** -->
>   **Controller A** pass parameter to **Controller B** and get's
>   JsonResult --> **Controller A** pass JSON back to **Client**.

What is the best way to approach this scenario??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `Controller A` really need to be the one to pass the result back to the client?  The client won't know the difference either way.  Generally I imagine you would use [RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter) to pass the control to `Controller B` and then the action on `Controller B` would return the JSON result, no different than if that action were called directly.

Comment: It is possible to pass parameter as Object (e.g Person) ?

return RedirectToAction("Action", new { person = curPersonObj });

Answer (score 3):

Perfect time to extract functionality from `ControllerB` to a separate class/method.

```
public class ControllerB
{
    public JsonResult Action()
    {
        return Foo.Action();
    } 
}
```