# mvc RedirectToAction passing a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, query-string, redirecttoaction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

I am in controller home, in ActionResult Id which has a list of string name **get** returned from a method. I want to RedirectToAction (Id2) using that list. In View -> Id2 the ViewData of that list name **get** is null, doesn;t contain the list of the Itemsn populated. How can I redirect from an actionResult to another view of another actionresult passing parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

If there are more than one parameters then:

```
return RedirectToAction("actionname", new { id = "id", name="name" }); // change parameters according to requirement
```

If you have only id as parameter then:

```
return RedirectToAction("actionname", new { id = "id" });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectToAction( new RouteValueDictionary( 
     new{ 
          controller = "mycontroller", 
          action = "myaction", 
          id = "MyId" 
     } 
));
```