# How to send value from a view to another in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

In a view `Index`, I have a DropDownList `Gamme`. I define its item selected in my view, like this :

```
public string SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }
```

In this view, I have a button `Appliquer`that took me to another view `Application`.

```
<input type="button" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="window.location = 'ProfileGa/Application'"/>
```

In the view `Application`, I have a button submit `Appliquer`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appl"   />
```

When I click on `Appliquer`, I want save the value selected in my DropDownList `Gamme` in my base.

The problem is that this value is passed `NULL` when i change the view (exit page Index and open Application).

I find that with Debugging.

The Controller action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult app(FlowViewModel model)
{
    Famille fam = new Famille();

    fam.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
    db.Familles.Add(fam);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Application"); 
}
```

***EDIT*** : 
In my view :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Appliquer", "Application", new { id=Model.SelectedProfile_Ga }) %>
```

In the action method (controller ProfileGa):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult appl(string id)
{
    FlowViewModel model = new FlowViewModel();
    Famille fam = new Famille();
    Profile_Ga profile_ga = db.Profil_Gas.Find(id);
    fam = db.Familles.Find(model.SelectedFamille);
    fam.ID_Gamme = model.SelectedProfile_Ga;
}
```

In the View application :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("appl", "ProfileGa")) { %>
    <input type="submit" value="Appliquer" id="appl"   />
<%}%>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use params? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter

Comment: I saw that,,,but the problem in my case, i don't have an Action method for the button that takes me to the other view,,,I have :
`<input type="button" value="Appliquer" id="appliquer" onclick="window.location = 'ProfileGa/Application'"/>`

Comment: But in this case you are just setting new url to website, instead of posting it back (with data) this is your problem.

Comment: ah ok ! so may i put an ActionLink ?? the problem that i want a button no link,,,is there is any way to post data with button ?

Comment: Of course, you have add another form and submit button to the controller.

Comment: hold on please, i will edit my question and show you what I did

Comment: Check now please, I try with an ActionLink,,,,but when I debug ,,I find that the value of `SelectedProfile_Ga`(which I want to take its value) is null .