# Id is always null in [HttpGet] action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am redirecting to another page with Id as a parameter. I passed Id successfully by using `RedirectToAction` but the `controller action` method is not accepting id and giving it `null` always even when there is Id in the url

Code to Redirect to that page

```
   return RedirectToAction("myaction", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(
                    new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", Id = 1 }));
```

Url looks like this

```
  http://localhost:1234/mycontroller/myaction/1
```

The `Action` looks llike this

```
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult myaction(int? Id)
  {
      // ID is null here 
  }
```

Comment: i saw in a tutorial. Is that wrong?

Comment: This post might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once

```
return RedirectToAction("myaction", "mycontroller", new {Id = 1} );
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("myaction", "mycontroller", 
       new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary( new { Id = 1 }));
```