# MVC5 route to different Controller's Action/View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC application for users to make requests, database schema something like this:

```
Request(RequestID, RequestType,...)

CarKey(CarKeyID, RequestID,...)

DoorKey(DoorKeyID, RequestID,...)
```

CarKey and DoorKey are different request types.

Let's say I have one CardKey request with a RequestID = 10, CarKeyID = 3, one DoorKey request with a RequestID = 11 and DoorKeyID = 4

My search result page shows all the requests with links like this:

```
http://localhost/Requests/10
```

When user click on this link, since it's a CarKey request, how do I route it to my CarKey controller's Edit action with RequestID = 10 or CarKeyID = 3 ?

Comment: How do you know it is a CarKey request from that URL?

Comment: That's my question. I was thinking if I can determine in the Request Controller's Details action and send it to CarKey controller Edit action with CarKeyID = 3?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found this is very useful:

[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

So What I did was to change return type in my RequestsController's Details action to

```
var carKeyID = request.CarKeys.First().CarKeyID;

return RedirectToAction("Edit","CarKeys", new { id = carKeyID});
```