# ViewBag.result is null in the View after setting in HttpPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a HttpPost method which I call a submit to database add transcation. If success, I set my viewbag.result = "successfully added"

```
var response =  UpdateDatabase(command);
if (response.success)
  viewbag.result = "successfully added";

RedirectToActoin("SubmitApplication");
```

In the view,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@ViewBag.result))
{
    <p> @ViewBag.result</p>
}
```

I placed a breakpoint and the viewbag.result is null.

I am not sure why the viewbag.result is null. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `TempData["Result"]` so that your data can be used after your redirect.

As MSDN states for `TempData`:

> Represents a set of data that persists only from one request to the next.

Also, see more information about usage here:

[viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)

Sample usage:

`TempData["Results"] = "successfully added";`

And in your `SubmitApplication` method:

`var message = (string)TempData["Results"];`

Always check for nulls etc which I have not done in this example.

Comment: It's better to use `TempData["Results"] as string` rather than `(string)TempData["Results"]`. The latter will raise an exception if the `TempData` value can't be casted to a string, but the former will merely set the variable to null. You should remove as many possibilities for an exception to be raise from a view as possible, since views aren't compiled until runtime. Even then, `TempData` is dynamic, so it's never evaluated until runtime.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - agreed!

Comment: Can't use TempData["Results"] because of the project. Is there anyway without turning on the session state?

Comment: Yes, you could try `return RedirctToAction("SubmitApplication", new {result = "successfully added"});` see here for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter