# MVC after finishing a job in controller 1 go to controller 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have following scenario: I have a web application, with this web application I can create a simple document. I have also two Controllers: the default `HomeController` and another `DocGenController`. I would like to return to the `DocGen.cshtml`-page after finishing a job in the `DocGenController`. At this time I implemented a normal return: `return View(../Home/DocGen.cshtml`.

But the problem is: if I use the `return View(../Home/DocGen.cshtml)`-statement it will take me only back to the page (Case 1)

How can I reach case 2?

[image: controller cases]

Comment: Like this? `return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return View("~/Views/Home/DocGen.cshtml")`;

Try

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
```

`RedirectToAction` method will send a 302 response to the client with `/Home/Index` as the location header value. The client browser will issue a new Http request for this url.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) to redirect form one controller to another view/controller. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter) is an answer using the redirect with parameters.