# Return to a named view doesn't work after form sumbit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

After POSTing to a server side method, I want to return the user back to the view from which he came, which was:

```
.../BrokerDashboard/Profile/Index
```

Here's the method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profile(ProfileModel Model)
{
    // do stuff
    return View("Index", Model);
}
```

There is logic in here that needs to execute after the form is posted:

```
public ActionResult Index(string contactid)
{
   // do stuff 
}
```

But after the post, the browser ends up here:

```
.../BrokerDashboard/Profile/Profile
```

Which means `public ActionResult Index()` does not get called again after the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think what your looking for is `RedirectToAction()` It causes a redirect and will fire your Index controller method.

[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Profile(ProfileModel Model)
{
    // do stuff
    return RedirectToAction("Index", Model);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I'm tracking.  But do I need to change the return type?  Now I get "not all code paths return a value."

Comment: You should return the result of that method (I'll update the answer)

Comment: Yep - realized that after I made the comment :-).  Thanks!  Testing