# send a value using RedirectToAction in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I' working on a MVC C# project and I have this action thata receives a string type id

```
public ActionResult Administracion(string id) 
        {
```

and I need to send the id value from another action (inside the same controller), this is what I have for the time being in the action from where I want to send the id

```
return RedirectToAction("Administracion");
```

my question is how to send the id using the RedirectToAction?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass route values as an optional argument to `RedirectToAction`.

```
return RedirectToAction("Administracion", new { id = "123" });
```

Edit: as others have noted this is a duplicate of another question.
[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: thanks, and in case I want to pass a property(the value of the property: clase.noDoc) I should use:  return RedirectToAction("Administracion", new { id = clase.noDoc.ToString() });   ??

Comment: Yes. The anonymous type object simply defines the names and values of the URL query string.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!