# asp.net core 2 razor pages route with id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

There are two page one is **Edit page** and the other is **Main Detail page** which is combined data of some entities
In edit page :
after edit done and I posted the data to API as below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(Guid id)
    {
        ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.Id = id;
        ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.ManufacturerId = GetManufacturerId(id);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await OnGetAsync(id);
            return Page();
        }
        HttpResponseMessage = await httpSystemApi.PutAsync("ManufacturerAuthorizedPersons", ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson);
        if (HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("../Detail", ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.ManufacturerId);
        }
        else
        {
            await OnGetAsync(id);
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

The ID in **OnPostMethod(Guid id)** is the value of edited entity. I am using the value and get the other one to use in route as **below** to get detail page.

```
ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.ManufacturerId = GetManufacturerId(id);
```

but on the detail page the value coming from route ID that I sent from Edit pages post method like below

```
 return RedirectToPage("../Detail", ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.ManufacturerId);
```

do not show up as route URL.Instead of ID is beeing same as I wa sent to Edit Page.
Little bit confused.
Need help please.

Comment: Why can't you redirect to action instead? Check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: Edit page location :  Pages/X/Y/Edit and Detail page location Pages/X/Detail so I use RedirectToPage methods.

Answer (score 27):

Suddenly I have found simpe solution to this problem. You should type:

```
return RedirectToPage("../Detail", new {id = ManufacturerAuthorizedPerson.ManufacturerId});
```