# RedirectToAction with complex-type parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, parameters, parameter-passing

I can't figure out how to send DTOs via a redirect.

I've tried everything I could find in both [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter) and [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680272(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

How can I accomplish this?

Below is a record of what I've tried and the results:

```
public ActionResult Create(ComRuleCompoundKeyDto ruleKey)
{
    var dto = new ComRuleOverrideDto()
    {
        Company = 42
    };
```

Sends null dtos:

```
    //var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary
    //{
    //    { "ruleKey", ruleKey },
    //    { "dto", dto },
    //};
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(MaintainOverride), routeValues);
```

Sends StupidDto filled with null:

```
    //var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new StupidDto
    //{
    //    ruleKey = ruleKey,
    //    dto = dto
    //});
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(MaintainOverride), routeValues);
```

Sends dtos filled with default values:

```
    //ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("ruleKey", ruleKey);
    //ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Add("dto", dto);
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(MaintainOverride));
```

Sends null dtos:

```
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(MaintainOverride), new { ruleKey, dto });
```

System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations:

```
    //return MaintainOverride(ruleKey, dto);

    return null;
}

public ActionResult MaintainOverride(ComRuleCompoundKeyDto ruleKey, ComRuleOverrideDto dto)
{
    var currencies = _srv.GetAllCurrenciesUsedByDealers().Select(x => x.CurrencyCode);

    var custTypes = _srv.GetAllCustomerTypes();
    var unitIds = _srv.GetUnitIds();
    var vm = new OverridesViewModel(currencies, custTypes, unitIds, ruleKey, dto);

    return View(vm);
}

public class StupidDto
{
    public ComRuleCompoundKeyDto ruleKey;
    public ComRuleOverrideDto dto;
}
```

Comment: Use TempData to pass data between functions

Comment: @FawadBinTariq From the linked Question, "Currently I'm stashing ID in tempdata, but when you hit f5 to refresh the page again after going back, the tempdata is gone and the page crashes." I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to make dto inside where you want , instead to passing.

Comment: @AsifRaza It's not possible to make the ruleKey, that has to be passed. And I intend to re-use the same MaintainOverride action for editing as well as creating, so at the very least I'd still need to send ID.

Comment: @Shyju The linked duplicate Question's Answer has "new StoreVm { Id=storeId, Name=store.Name,Code=store.Code};". Those are primitive types. When I tried the same with complex types, they were sent as null. Or is the answer simply that it cannot be done like that, and I'd have to expand out all the contained types in my DTOs down to their primitives?

Comment: So the essence is, you should not try to send complex objects in redirect response. Pass only the minimal information needed (like a Unique Id) and query it again in the GET action (That is the PRG pattern). If do not want to do that, use TempData

Comment: @Shyju I see. Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by explicitly setting the View's name (nameof(MaintainOverride)) when returning another action (as opposed to redirecting).

```
public ActionResult Create(ComRuleCompoundKeyDto ruleKey)
{
    var dto = new ComRuleOverrideDto()
    {
        Company = 42
    };

    return MaintainOverride(ruleKey, dto);
}

public ActionResult MaintainOverride(ComRuleCompoundKeyDto ruleKey, ComRuleOverrideDto dto)
{
    var currencies = _srv.GetAllCurrenciesUsedByDealers().Select(x => x.CurrencyCode);

    var custTypes = _srv.GetAllCustomerTypes();
    var unitIds = _srv.GetUnitIds();
    var vm = new OverridesViewModel(currencies, custTypes, unitIds, ruleKey, dto);

    return View(nameof(MaintainOverride), vm);
}
```

Comment: I'd still like to know why RedirectToAction isn't working, though.