# ASP.NET MVC5 problem in passing data between Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a basic Car Rental Application. The user can view the cars and click the `Rent` button. After clicking it, I need to return a new `View` which contains a form, that the user has to complete in order to finish the order. I am having problems passing the `Car` data as well as the `Customer` data between the controllers in order to complete the `Rent`.

On the main page, I have a **Rent** link under every car. Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Rent", "Rent" , new { Id = car.Id})</p>
</div>
```

`Rent` method from `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult Rent(string id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Rents");
}
```

`Create` method from `RentsController`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string carId, Rent rent)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    var carToRent = context.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == carId);

    if (carToRent == null)
        return Content($"Car not found!");


    rent.Car = carToRent;

    var customer = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == User.Identity.Name);

    if (customer == null)
        return Content($"Customer not found!");

    rent.Customer = customer;

    context.Rents.Add(rent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I am getting an HTTP 404 Error every time I try to access `Rents/Create`.

Comment: try RedirectToAction("Create", "Rents", new { carId=id, rent = RentObject}); 

you did not pass the parameters. This causes the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: @VecihiBaltacı is correct as that is the direct source of your error however from the code you posted and use case listed, it doesn't look like you need to pass a `Rent` object in to `Create` at all. Just create a new one inside the method. See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify what you're attempting to do. Main points to note are the following:

- You don't need to link to the `Rent` action if all it does is
  redirect to the `Create` action- just link to the `Create` action
  directly. There is another overload of `ActionLink` that will let you specify
  the controller (see below).
- From what you've posted it doesn't look like the `Create` action
  needs to take in a parameter for `Rent rent`- this can be created
  inside the `Create` action and simplify the data that you need to
  pass from view to controller.

Please see my comments in code for further explanantion:

View:

```
//call the Create action on the RentsController directly from the view
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Rent", "Create", "Rents" , new { Id = car.Id }, null)</p>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
//modify signature to remove passing a Rent object it
//you can create this object inside of this method
//and do not need to pass one in so remove it from the method signature
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string carId)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    var carToRent = context.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == carId);

    if (carToRent == null)
        return Content($"Car not found!");

    var rent = new Rent(); //this line has been added since the method signature was changed
    rent.Car = carToRent;

    var customer = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.UserId == User.Identity.Name);

    if (customer == null)
        return Content($"Customer not found!");

    rent.Customer = customer;

    context.Rents.Add(rent);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and finally you can remove the following:

```
//delete this action entirely, if youre doing nothing other than redirecting 
//to an action then just link directly to the action you want
//notice the ActionLink in the view is modified to hit the Create action directly
public ActionResult Rent(string id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Rents");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below you can pass parameters in RedirectToAction() method.

```
RedirectToAction(String, String, RouteValueDictionary)
```

Redirects to the specified action using the action name, controller name, and route values. Try to redirect Create action with the carId and Rent object.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know using multiple post object, but you can post one post object like that

```
public class MyPostObject
{
    public string carId { get; set; }
    public Rent rent{ get; set; }
}
```

and post it like that

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyPostObject myPostObject)
{
   string carId=myPostObject.carId;
   Rent rent = myPostObject.rent;
   ....

}
```

**UPDATE :** Or you can use multiple post object with Ajax

```
    $("#btnSave").on('click', function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Rent")';

        //Rent class properties
        var data=
             {
                 Brand: 'Renault',
                 Model: 'Megan',
             };
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                carId:'12',
                rent:data
            },
            datatype:'json',
            ContentType:'application/json;utf-8'
        }).done(function(resp){
            alert('Success ' +resp);
        }).error(function(err){
            alert("Error " + err.status);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You either have not passed the parameters or you are missing the below method if you are looking to return a view with your redirect

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{ 
   return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you will have to pass the required parameters into the redirect statement.

```
public ActionResult Rent(string id)
{
    Rent rentItem = new Rent();

    return RedirectToAction("Create", "Rents", new { carId = id, rent = rentItem});
}
```