# Passing parameter value from an action result to another in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, parameter-passing

Im new in MVC and im having a hard time passing a string parameter value (subjectid) to another action result in the same controller.

I badly need help.

[Controller - ActionResult Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GDgo.png)

[Controller - ActionResult Forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiZnI.png)

ActionResult Content needs to pass the ticketcontent to a view. Will still i be able to use the RedirectToAction? Any other solution/s please.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using RedirectToAction()? What error do you get? Take a look at below if it helps.

[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: If i use RedirectToAction how will i render the view for may ActionResult Content?

Comment: Do you want to execute Controller - ActionResult Forward in the same request? I believe this would be executed/invoked from some view and you can pass required parameters via route parameters or query strings.