# Alternative to TempData on redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, tempdata

In old legacy project we have a lot of code like this:

```
var result = someService.AddRecord(data);
TempData["Success"] = result.Success;
TempData["Message"] = result.Message;
return RedirectToAction("Rakamakafo");
```

But then we faced the situation when requests processed serial in controller, which caused by locking nature of `Session` object and solved this by turning `Session` to read-only:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

It's all good except `TempData` object (which relies on session) stopped working.

How this can be solved in clean way without rewriting whole application to AJAX?

Comment: I guess by writing your code on base controller and then using data on all pages pages or wherever you need

Comment: @Shubham I'm doing something like this, but what to do with redirects?
Now I'm investigating cookies, maybe they will help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter

Comment: @KevinGosse miss.

Answer (score 0):

Done it using cookies. First, I'd created `BaseController` with `ShowMessageAfterRedirect(bool success, string message)` and set two cookies (`message_success` and `message_caption`), then in message displaying partial view I'm taking data back from cookies and deleting them.