# Pass TempData between Contollers for Modal return Null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, tempdata

I want to pass Some String between two controllers to show successful login with modal.I read this topics :
[ViewBag, ViewData and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata)
and
[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

but it doesn't work for me and TempData returns Null.it's works fine in this Controllers.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginConfirm(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user!=null)
        {
            var status = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Pass,model.RememberMe,true);
            if (status.Succeeded)
            {
                TempData["msg"] = "You Login successful ";
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
        }
        TempData["msg"] = "Somethings Wrong!";

        return View("Login");
    }
```

Comment: Please show the StartUp class

Comment: It's My Startup class :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two way

1)
when you using the

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

you enable the GDPR ( General Data Protection Regulation ) And so for as long as the user does not accept your cookie, you will not be able to set cookie in site. And that makes the TempData empty.

2)
After Migrating to ASP Core 2.1 I had this issue and after working for a day find the solution:

in Startup.Configure() app.UseCookiePolicy(); should be after app.UseMVC();

Comment: Oh. Thanks Its Work Now Farhad <3

Comment: Good luck... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace GiftSite
{
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        //app.UseHttpMethodOverride();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

}