# Asp.net mvc redirect to action from a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to write a method in a  class in a Asp.Net mvc application that (will be called from a controller and) redirects to a action and also supplies a parameter.
Something like.

```
 public class someClass
    {
        public object Redirect(string action, string controller)
        {
            //some code
            return RedirectToAction(action, controller new {parameter=xxx});
        }
    }`
```

Thanks

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Try inheriting the Controller class as

```
public class SomeClass : Controller
{
  public object Redirect(string action, string controller)
        {
            //some code
            return RedirectToAction(action, controller new {parameter=xxx});
        }
}
```

Though, by inheriting this class though you make your class a controller