# Get Newly Created DB ID to pass to Quote Method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

EDIT: I have the Quote working on EDIT, but it's not working on Create.  I've adjusted my method from my original post. So my issue is I cannot figure out to pass the ID of a newly created record to the quote method.

Student here!
Creating an MVC app and I cannot figure out I'm missing.  I thought I had it working and then I moved on, but when I went back to test, I realized it wasn't working and am getting a bunch of errors.  I know the reason is because the values I think I'm passing aren't actually being passed.

I have the two scenarios, Create and Edit and when the DB entry is created it should redirect to my quote method, but that is where I'm getting errors.  I can't figure out how to pass the values that were just created to the quote method. Any suggestions as to what I'm missing would be appreciated!

This is my controller:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CarInsurance.Models;
using CarInsurance.View_Models;

namespace CarInsurance.Controllers
{
    public class InsureeController : Controller
    {
        private InsuranceEntities db = new InsuranceEntities();



        // GET: Insuree/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Insuree insuree = db.Insurees.Find(id);
            if (insuree == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(insuree);
        }

        // GET: Insuree/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Insuree/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,DateOfBirth,CarYear,CarMake,CarModel,DUI,SpeedingTickets,CoverageType")] Insuree insuree)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Insurees.Add(insuree);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Quote", insuree);
        }

        // GET: Insuree/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Insuree insuree = db.Insurees.Find(id);

            if (insuree == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(insuree);
        }

        // POST: Insuree/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress,DateOfBirth,CarYear,CarMake,CarModel,DUI,SpeedingTickets,CoverageType")] Insuree insuree)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(insuree).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Quote", insuree);

        }



        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        // GET: Quote
        public ActionResult Quote(int? id)
        {
            Insuree insuree = db.Insurees.Find(id);
            Quote quote = new Quote();
            quote.FirstName = insuree.FirstName;
            quote.LastName = insuree.LastName;
            quote.EmailAddress = insuree.EmailAddress;
            quote.DateOfBirth = insuree.DateOfBirth;
            quote.CarYear = insuree.CarYear;
            quote.CarMake = insuree.CarMake;
            quote.CarModel = insuree.CarModel.ToLower();
            quote.DUI = Convert.ToBoolean(insuree.DUI);
            quote.SpeedingTickets = insuree.SpeedingTickets;
            quote.CoverageType = Convert.ToBoolean(insuree.CoverageType);

            var age = DateTime.Now.Year - insuree.DateOfBirth.Year;
            decimal totalQuote = 50;
            // Age Constraints
            if (age <= 18)
            {
                totalQuote += 100;
                quote.quoteAge = 100;
            }

            if (age >= 19 && age <= 25)
            {
                totalQuote += 50;
                quote.quoteAge = 50;
            }
            if (age > 25)
            {
                totalQuote += 25;
                quote.quoteAge = 25;
            }

            // Car Constraints
            if (quote.CarYear < 2000 || quote.CarYear > 2015)
            {
                totalQuote += 25;
                quote.quoteCar = 25;
            }
            if (quote.CarMake == "porsche")
            {
                totalQuote += 25;
                quote.quoteCar += 25;
            }
            if (quote.CarModel == "911 carrera")
            {
                totalQuote += 25;
                quote.quoteCar += 25;

            }
            // Driving History Constraints
            if (quote.SpeedingTickets > 0)
            {
                totalQuote += quote.SpeedingTickets * 10;
                quote.quoteTickets = quote.SpeedingTickets * 10;
            }
            if (quote.DUI)
            {
                totalQuote *= Convert.ToDecimal(1.25);
                quote.quoteDUI = totalQuote * Convert.ToDecimal(.25);
            }

            // Coverage Requested
            if (quote.CoverageType)
            {
                totalQuote *= Convert.ToDecimal(1.50);
            }
            ViewBag.Quote = Math.Round(totalQuote, 2);
            return View(quote);
        }

    }
}
```

And my quote class if needed:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CarInsurance.View_Models
{
    public class Quote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int CarYear { get; set; }
        public string CarMake { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }
        public bool DUI { get; set; }
        public int SpeedingTickets { get; set; }
        public bool CoverageType { get; set; }
        public decimal quoteAge { get; set; }
        public decimal quoteCar { get; set; }
        public decimal quoteTickets { get; set; }
        public decimal quoteDUI { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK done!  Any suggestion as to how I can fix my problem?

Comment: There are a few ways to go about this. When you SaveChanges() your object will have its new id automatically if you configure it as a database generated id. Maybe you can get some inspiration [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: @Crowcoder yes...I found that since posting so this is what I'm doing with my return: ` return RedirectToAction("Quote", new { id = insuree.Id});`.  When I debug now, It is saying that ModelStat.IsValid is false so it is passing over the add insuree to db and save changes.  Why would it be false?

Comment: OK it has something to do with my checkboxes.  Error in the ModelState says the value "on" is not valid.