# How to redirect to action when action contains route attribute

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Controller

```
public class TestController{
   
   [Route("TestIndex")]
   public ActionResult Index(){
   }
}
```

html

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","TestController")">Go to test</a>
```

I have above code!!

**On Go to test click I want to redirect to Index action of Testcontroller** for that I used below code

```
href="@Url.Action("Index","TestController")"
```

but I think as route attribute is used there that's why it is not redirecting to that action

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a bug in your code, should be

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Test")">Go to test</a>
```

or maybe

```
<a href="@Url.Action("TestIndex","Test")">Go to test</a>
```

You have to use something one - absolute route, or relative. Since you didnt post a controller route and your config endpoints, I can not understand what route you really need, but try this, it will certainly work

```
<a href="~/test/testIndex">Go to test</a>
```

and route

```
 [Route("~/Test/TestIndex")]
   public ActionResult Index(){
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,I tried with above solution too but in this case my url will get changed.

Comment: @Pran Sorry, but I don' t understand what you mean.  There are only two results - It calls action or not.

Comment: it worked I used href="~/testIndex"

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has built in methods for this such as `RedirectToAction` See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

A usage would look like:
`return RedirectToAction("controller", "method");`

To pass route attributes simply use:

```
return RedirectToAction("controller","method", new { id });
```

If that doesn't work either try using:
[RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter/1300844#1300844)

```
return RedirectToAction( "Main", new RouteValueDictionary( 
    new { controller = controllerName, action = "Main", Id = Id } ) );
```

As some people have noted the other example not working for them.