# Send Query String of Current View/URL to another Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to send current url query string to Action but the value is empty
inside second Action

```
    public ActionResult Edit(string userId) // start action
    {
        try
        {
            var userID = userId.Unprotect<int>("userId");
            return View(model: person);
        }
        catch
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
```

URL

```
http://localhost:25388/Home/Edit?userId=MsIJTy8Ea6ixr1E3xafN2SoUkHrXon3jcUMnlHPMaTZPW7XYma5Wqtkr9JGn4Ue8PImfNw%3D%3D
```

and the destination action method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditSubmit(string userID, Person person) // second action
    {
        var test = Request.QueryString;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

is there any way to receive first action/url query strings inside second action?
(I mean receive the value of userId )

```
userId=MsIJTy8Ea6ixr1E3xafN2SoUkHrXon3jcUMnlHPMaTZPW7XYma5Wqtkr9JGn4Ue8PImfNw%3D%3D
```

Comment: What is in your Routing config?

Comment: default routing configs @klekmek

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RedirectToAction with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257482/redirecttoaction-with-parameter)

Comment: no i want to know that is it possible to send URL querystring data of old URL/Action to new Action

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i reached my goal with sending current URL QueryString part with Form submit Part
here is the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditSubmit", "Home", new {userId = Request.QueryString["userId"]}, FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
}
```

here is the main part

```
Request.QueryString["userId"] (inside view)
```